# Can I get gradle to update my existing Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, logback

I'm new to Gradle, so please excuse me if this question seems naive or simple.

My eclipse project exists and works well and I want to add Logback for my logging.  It is easy enough to get the dependencies set up in build.gradle...

```
dependencies {
    groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '1.8.3'

    // Logback dependencies    
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.3'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.3'
}
```

...and this allows my build to succeed, but how can I get it to update the "Referenced Libraries" section of my eclipse project?  In other words, can I get gradle to update eclipse's .classpath adding the appropriate  entries for any new libraries that are brought in via the gradle dependencies?

As it currently stands, I have to figure out where in ~/.gradle the dependencies became JAR files and by hand I create Reference Libraries to point at them.  Yuk.  There has to be a way to automate this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Gradle Eclipse Plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html).

Just add `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` at the beginning of your `build.gradle` and then try running `gradle eclipse`. This will generate all eclipse settings files based on your gradle set-up.

If you need to just generate `.classpath` you can do so by running `gradle eclipseClasspath`.